# Why is `popd` popping the wrong directory?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

Is this expected behavior from `popd`?

```
>>> dirs -v
0 dirA
1 dirB
>>> dirs +0
dirA
>>> popd -n +0
dirA
>>> dirs -v
0 dirA
```

I would expect the last line to tell me that only dirB remained in the stack. I don't see why it removed dirB.

This is GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0). My pushd and popd have been turned into functions by rvm, but even if I unset them and use the built-ins, the behavior is the same. So I presume I'm misunderstanding the semantics of popd.

Here dirA is the working dir. The manual does say "The current directory is always the first directory in the stack", but it also says you can pop things off the stack, so maybe this is a weird gray area, where you try to pop the top element off the stack while suppressing the `cd` action.

From the manual:

> Removes elements from the directory stack. The elements are numbered
> from 0 starting at the first directory listed by dirs; that is, popd
> is equivalent to popd +0.
>
> When no arguments are given, popd removes the top directory from the
> stack and changes to the new top directory.
>
> Arguments, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>
> -n Suppresses the normal change of directory when removing directories from the stack, so that only the stack is manipulated.
>
> +N Removes the Nth directory (counting from the left of the list printed by dirs), starting with zero, from the stack.
>
> -N Removes the Nth directory (counting from the right of the list printed by dirs), starting with zero, from the stack.
>
> If the top element of the directory stack is modified, and the -n
> option was not supplied, popd uses the cd builtin to change to the
> directory at the top of the stack. If the cd fails, popd returns a
> non-zero value.
>
> Otherwise, popd returns an unsuccessful status if an invalid option is
> encountered, the directory stack is empty, or a non-existent directory
> stack entry is specified.
>
> If the popd command is successful, Bash runs dirs to show the final
> contents of the directory stack, and the return status is 0.

Comment: the top of the stack is current directory, you've asked to remove the top of the stack (+0)  without changing directory (-n), therefore the top of the stack must remain the current directory

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't understand. Why was dirB removed?

Comment: it wasn't ... dirA was removed, and since you supplied `-n` then dirB was replaced by your current path ... which presumable was dirA ... try with more paths in the stack, and try with and without `-n` option to get a feel for what is actually happening

Comment: @JaromandaX So your claim is that the semantics are: (1) Execute whatever operation the user requested, then (2) *Replace* the top item on the stack with the working directory (erasing it if it is not the working directory)? That claim is consistent with the evidence, but not supported by the manual, indeed, the manual is vague.

Comment: I don't *claim* a thing. I test and observe and read the documentation to understand what is going on